# Topology was destroyed when call an api from Heroku to mLab

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mlab

My database is `MongoDb` I create a node.js file in `Heroku` to call an api to `mLab`.

My api worked very well before today.

But when i try to call api i get the error `Topology was destroyed` this day.

https://obscure-reaches-65656.herokuapp.com/api/thisWeek

I test it in my localhost, it is still working.

I have no idea what happens between `Heroku` and `mLab`

May be the information from `mLab` is the reason ?

```
 Hello from mLab,

You are receiving this email because you have one or more mLab Sandbox deployments in the "motogod19" mLab account that will be affected by upcoming maintenance.

On Friday, July 20 2018 we will start a three-day maintenance window to upgrade all free Sandbox databases running MongoDB 3.4 to MongoDB 3.6. On this day, MongoDB 3.6 will also become mLab's default release version for all new deployments.
```

Maintenance will cause the error ?
[image]

I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: restart your app by typing `heroku restart -a app_name`

Comment: Thanks for your help, the issue seems like is connection problem. I get it now.